# Character Gaps On Comic Conversation : 3

Tags: character-identification, traditional-characters

Here is the work that I have done so far. Thank you for any help finding the missing characters (I don't need the translations, per se but just seeing a clear copy of the character would be helpful).

I have some problems with seeing some characters in this older copy of a book (the Chinese character is sometimes too dark to distinguish strokes and scanning doesn't help).

There are multiple questions because I want to show the work in context. I could break these up into smaller questions but that would not be helpful to other learners (learning conversation) and would unnecessarily clog the website.

> **四十分鐘後會 (？) 火 (？)**
>
> **。。。。(？) 有半個人在**
>
> **Also not sure how to interpret the characters on the last panel**

Here is what I have so far:
*(Please let me know if anything is wrong)*

> 是誰在說話？
>   (Who is talking?)
>
> 快出來！
>   (Come out!)
>
> 好可怕！
>   (<del>Awful!</del> How Scary!)

[image: doraemon-1-3]

### UPDATE

(Based on answers, please note the updates. Thanks for the help.)

> **四十分鐘後會 (？) 火 (？)** ➾ 四十分钟后会被火烤
>
> **。。。。(？) 有半個人在**  ➾ 没有半个人在
>
> **Also not sure how to interpret the characters on the last panel**  ➾ 咚卡咚 (appears to be sounds)

Comment: Voting to reopen this question. Translations are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated. I do clearly show prior research. Everyone who has learned has at times been unable to recognize a character and has been helped by a person. In this example, I did not recognize some characters so I show the entire conversation in context. I provide the characters that I do recognize to show prior effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`四十分钟后会被火烤` (it) will be roasted (by fire) in forty minutes

`没有半个人在` there's not even half-a-person here!

`咚卡咚` onomatopoeia (maybe like 'den den den' or whatever)

the only correction I would make is on your `好可怕！ (Awful!)` I would translate this as `how scary!` instead...